# ZendFramework 2:Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias:

Tags: zend-db, zend-framework2, zend-paginator

I am a new at Zendframework 2. I am trying to join two tables and display the result.

The two tables are. 
Works and Artist . The tables are joined based on artist_id.

STEP 1> Created 2 class(Works , Artist) in Model
STEP 2> In WorksTable I have the following code

```
class WorksTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
     protected $table ='works';

    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
        {

        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->resultSetPrototype = new HydratingResultSet(
                new ArraySerializableHydrator(),
                new Works()
        );
        $this->resultSetPrototype->buffer(); 
        $this->initialize();
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $select = $this->getSql()->select();
        $select->join('works','artists.artist_id = artist_id ');


        //create paginator object to display records
        $paginator =  new Paginator(
                new DbSelect($select, $this->adapter, $this->resultSetPrototype)
        );

        return $paginator;

    }

}
```

STEP 3> In controller I defined the following code

```
public function searchAction()
    { 
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $paginator = $this->getWorksTable()->fetchAll();
 //         $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(12);
        $vm = new ViewModel(array(
                'poster' => $paginator,
        ));
        $vm->setVariable('paginator', $paginator);
        return $vm;   
    }
```

For statement $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(12); get error

Message:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'works'
```

Has anyone come across this error? Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you join `works` table to itself, mysql treat it as two separate tables joined but with same name, hence the error.

Use alias for table you join:

```php
$select = $this->getSql()->select();
$select->join(array('w' => 'works'),'artists.artist_id = artist_id ');
```

but it looks like it is just typo there and table should be `artists`

Answer (score 0):

There hasn't used `artists` table begin the query.and also didn't use `works` table on join.

```
 use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect;
 use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
 public function fetchAll()
 {
    $sql = new Sql($this->tableGateway->getAdapter());
    $select = new Select();
    $select->from("artists");
    $select->columns(array('*'));
    $select->join('works','artists.artist_id = works.artist_id',array('your_wanted_column_names,don't mention again artist_id here because there should be a error'));

    $paginator =  new Paginator(
            new DbSelect($select, $this->adapter, $this->resultSetPrototype)
    );

    return $paginator;
```